Return reference to hashset entry using a hashset reference in struct
I am currently writing a parser in rust, and I need to be able to intern string literals and variable identifiers. The parser should borrow a HashSet to add the values to, and return tokens with references to these values.
A simplified version of my code is as follows (returns references by themselves instead of in tokens, but same idea)
use std::collections::HashSet;

struct Parser<'a> {
    interned_strings: &'a mut HashSet<String>
}

impl<'a> Parser<'a> {
    fn parse<'slf>(&'slf mut self, foo: String) -> &'slf str {
        if self.interned_strings.contains(&foo) {
            self.interned_strings.get(&foo).unwrap()
        } else {
            self.interned_strings.insert(foo.clone());
            self.interned_strings.get(&foo).unwrap()
        }
    }
}

If I then try to use it I get an error telling me that parser does not live long enough.
pub fn main() {
    let mut strings = HashSet::new();
    let foo = {
        let mut parser = Parser { interned_strings: &mut strings };
        parser.parse("foo".into())
    };
    // Error: Parser doesn't live long enough
    println!("{}", foo)
}

This makes sense, but I should be able to access foo even after Parser is dropped, *foo should point to the HashSet, so I tried changing Parser::parse to the following:
fn parse<'slf>(&'slf mut self, foo: String) -> &'a str {
    if self.interned_strings.contains(&foo) {
        // Lifetime error!
        self.interned_strings.get(&foo).unwrap()
    } else {
        self.interned_strings.insert(foo.clone());
        self.interned_strings.get(&foo).unwrap()
    }
}

Changing the returned lifetime from 'slf to 'a (lifetime of the HashSet reference) removes the error in main(), but now the borrow checker is saying that the value self.interned_strings.get(&foo).unwrap() doesn't live long enough.
The error says: "method was supposed to return data with lifetime `'a` but it is returning data with lifetime `'slf`"
I'm not sure how to resolve this, as a reference to the HashSet entry should have the same lifetime as the HashSet itself, the data won't be dropped just because the Parser that inserted it is. Should I use unsafe of is there a safe alternative?

You can't give out references to the contained hash set that outlast 'slf that would create multiple aliasing references to the same data, the one in Parser and the one you gave out. Or in other words, you can't implement your semantics with references internally.

If an insertion to the HashSet causes it to reallocate, any previously issued references would be invalidated.  This probably isn't what you want of an arena.  You need to reconsider your design.

The 'slf lifetime is redundant and you have repeated what the compiler, by default, does; when there is only one reference in the arguments (e.g. &self), the returnee's lifetime is considered the argument lifetime. Consequently, lifetime annotation is optional in this case in contrast to the very early version of Rust.
